# Domestic travel with ID not containing surname

Tags: paperwork, airports, india, domestic-travel, air-india

Is it ok to travel when I have mistakenly written my surname on my domestic air India ticket, but I don't have any proof of ID containing my surname?

My husband is travelling with me, and he has the surname on his ID and my ID contains his name with surname.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.airindia.in/new-correct-name-bookings.htm passengers are required to make their bookings in their correct and full names. For Indian domestic passengers that name should match with Aadhaar Card, if available.

A list of acceptable ID is available here http://www.airindia.in/new-documents-to-carry.htm

I’d recommend you contact the airline to clarify whether you’ll be allowed to board.